# Preference words close together in ElasticSearch / Lucene?

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

Are there options to make it so ElasticSearch ranks higher queries where the searched-for words appear closer to each other in the document?

For some context, I am working on a legal research product. Oftentimes, someone will search for a concept, like the False Claims Act, by simply putting those words into our search box. However, those words are REALLY common in our database, including in documents about totally unrelated things, so the results are disappointing.

It would be amazing if I could tell ElasticSearch to take into account in its scoring algorithm results that have the words in close proximity.

Comment: what do you mean by 'closer'?

Comment: I mean that the searched-for words have relatively few words between them -- the fewer the better. As Andrei pointed out in his answer, it's slop in ElasticSearch-land

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever query you have now, there must be something that computes a score, otherwise you wouldn't be interested in scoring higher or lower.

Take whatever you have now and put that in a `bool` `should`. Add another `should` statement that should use either a [`match_phrase` with `slop`s](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_closer_is_better.html) or one of the [span queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-span-near-query.html).

For example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "some_text_field",
            "query": "False Claims Act"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "some_text_field": {
              "query": "False Claims Act",
              "slop": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Every should will contribute to the final score of the documents. The query above will somewhat "boost" the final score by considering those documents that match `False Claims Act` as better.

The `slop` is there to indicate how "close" you want those words to be.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for, thank you. Is there a way to tune how much the "should" query influences relevance? Also, is there a way to make it a function of slop rather than hard-coding the distance? Otherwise we'll just have a bunch of "should" queries, like at 0, 50, 100 etc., and that feels hacky.

Comment: Boosting is a broader subject and it depends on other parts of the query. For example, you could use this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html. What do you mean by "function of slop"?

Comment: What I meant by that was gradually increase the boost score the closer the words are together. So if the words are `n` words apart would score slightly worse (lower) than `n-1`, which would score slightly worse than `n-2`, etc. -- so that the closer the words are, the higher the matching score is boosted.